# Parallelization of os.walk()

Tags: python

I have a large directory structure hosted on a network storage device that I'd like to traverse using `os.walk`. The system is rather slow, but I think the process could be done quicker if I could query multiple directories at the same time (all with the same common root). I don't care what order the outputs come in, so long as by the end I have parsed everything.

I'm thinking of re-implementing `os.walk` to pass new directories into a pool of threaded workers. I'd much rather use someone else's code if it already exists (why reinvent the wheel?), but haven't come across any.

Surely this is a common task? Has anyone come across something like this before? Maybe I'm missing something and it wouldn't result in a speedup.

If I don't get an answer in a week or so, no doubt I'll post my attempt here.

Comment: You might be moving the bottleneck from your software to the hardware. Do you have the hardware and o/s configuration for your computer to read, simultaneously, from more than one location on your storage device ?  If each of your os walkers is trying to read through the same channel the contention between them is likely to outweigh any speedup you expect to gain.

Comment: I don't know too much about the backend infrastructure. The network storage is a large corporate system, mounted as a Samba share on Windows 7. I'm assuming it has the capability to run more queries as it's used by 100s of users at the same time, and that the slowness is a result of latency between my machine and the off-site storage. If this is the case then I expect that submitting multiple queries at the same time will get the job done quicker.

Comment: Yes, given your description of your infrastructure it sounds as if there is the hardware, at least, for multiple i/o channels.  Without a lot more detail I'm not going to hazard a guess about the performance of your approach.  But, I remain prepared to be unsurprised if you find that multiple simultaneous queries (all of which will incur the latency you mention) do not perform better than one humongous query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a distributed job execution system. I've been working with [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) for a while and find it a great framework, if you don't want to start with the basic Thread module, I'll recommend it. It supports clients and workers written in Python, so maybe fit your needs. But you may still need to do the division job.

Comment: Gearman looks perhaps a little overkill for the task I have in mind.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid of that too. But honestly the installation of gearman could be very fast so doesn't take too much effort.